# Show that $(a^2-b^2)(a^4-b^4) \leq (a^3-b^3)^2$ and $(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)\geq(a^3+b^3)^2$ for all $a,b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Show that $(a^2-b^2)(a^4-b^4) \leq (a^3-b^3)^2$ and $(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)\geq(a^3+b^3)^2$ for all $a,b$.

I'm basically new to inequality. I'm starting my first inequality book which is [Introduction to Inequality](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856034)

So this is the first question I stuck on. Hope someone could provide some hints for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: expand out both and eliminate common terms. You should find that both come down to the same inequality; divide out by a common factor and you should find a pretty simple AGM instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the first one. It's a good idea to take the difference
of the two sides, viz.,
$$
\begin{align}
&(a^3-b^3)^2-(a^2-b^2)(a^4-b^4)\\
&=-2a^3b^3+a^4b^2+a^2b^4\\
&=a^2b^2(a^2-2ab+b^2).
\end{align}
$$
Can you see why this expression is $\ge0$?

Comment: So it means $a^2b^2(a-b)^2 \geq 0$. Am I right>

Comment: @Mathxx Yes, indeed you are.

Comment: Yea. I solved both inequalities. Thanks a lot!

I'm so stupid that I didn't notice this trick!

Answer (score 1):

For the second one.

By Cauchy- Schwarz, $(a^2+b^2)((a^2)^2+(b^2)^2) \geqslant (a \cdot a^2+b \cdot b^3)^2=(a^3+b^3)^2$

Comment: Will come back for it when I've learnt Cauchy-Schwarz !